# Uncaught TypeError: this.resultContinuation_0 is undefined when trying to run a suspend function in Kotlin JS Browser onclick

Tags: kotlin, gradle, simulator, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-js

I'm working on a multi-platform RISC-V simulator in `Kotlin` and I've been stuck on a problem for more than a week now. I've tried everything that I could find online but I had no luck with it.

To give you a little context:
I'm trying to bind [this](https://github.com/ThaumicMekanism/venus) project ([here](https://ufile.io/zvy8f26g) you can download my code) to the [VMB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vmb/) (virtual motherboard, [here](https://ufile.io/z5elw82w) you can download the latest, not yet published version) via `WebSockets`. I've already done the communication part and also tested it on the `JVM` branch (I've also made another small Kotlin JS [project](https://github.com/benny1611/korio-websockets-test) with just the code for the communication part and it works fine, but for some reason when I put everything together it just doesn't work). It builds without any error and it even works fine (to an extend), until I try to connect to the `VMB`, then I get an error in the Browser's console saying `Uncaught TypeError: this.resultContinuation_0 is undefined`. I've lost so many hours on this problem and I'm pretty sure it's just something small (maybe even obvious) that I'm missing.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Download the projects (you will need both `venus` and `VMB`)
2. Download and install [`grunt`](https://gruntjs.com/) on your machine if you don't have it
3. In the `vmb` folder double click on `mother.exe` and be sure to click on the power button (it works only on windows, sorry)
4. Open the `venus` project in `InteliJ` and build it using `gradle` (`IntelliJ` usually recognizes the project as `gradle` automatically)
5. After the build is completed, open a `Powershell` or `cmd` in the `venus` folder and run `grut dist`
6. The results should now be in the `out` directory.
7. You will probably need [`XAMPP`](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) to host the files on a server locally in case you get a `CORS Error`
8. When you open the page go to the `Simulator` tab and then click on `Assemble & Simulate from Editor` button.
9. You should now be able to see the error in the console.

Any help is highly appreciated as I've been stuck on this issue for days now. Thank you!

EDIT:

Upon further digging I noticed that the problem appears whenever I call a `suspend` function `onclick`.

For example:
I made a function in `Driver.kt`:

```
    @JsName("connect")
    suspend fun connect() {
        sim.connectToMotherboard()
    }
```

Where `connectToMotherboard()` is a suspended function, that I call whenever a button is pressed.

HTML:

```
<button class="button is-primary" onclick="driver.connect()">Connect to Motherboard</button>
```

This gives me the same error as mentioned in the title. After I downloaded `Firefox` for developers I've got this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "context", this.resultContinuation_0 is undefined
```

Comment: can you include a snippet of the code that is throwing this exception please

Comment: The problem is that I don't know exactly which line is causing this error, I've also made a small project that includes only the communication part (just so that I can see what is going on and also to build the project faster). I want to integrate the small project into ```venus```. The problem is, when I run the small project, it connects with the ```VMB``` just fine, but when I try to integrate it into the main project, it gives me this error. Here is the small project: https://github.com/benny1611/korio-websockets-test

Comment: Here is the project again without the integration, this will not build as I call a ```suspend``` function in a "normal" function in ```Driver.kt``` in front-end. Link: https://ufile.io/hsiwsl2j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I called some `@JSName` functions in my HTML code. Something like this:

```
@JsName("doSomething")
suspend fun doSomething() {
    // some code...
}
```

And then in my HTML code I had some lines like this:

```
<button id="someButton" class="button" onclick="doSomething()">Click Me</button>
```

The key here is the `suspend` keyword. If you call a "normal" function from JS/HTML there's no problem, but a `suspend` function cannot be called from HTML. It has to be in a `launch` block or a `Coroutine` because otherwise the `Continuation` will be `null`. So I changed the `kotlin` code to something like this:

```
val myButton = document.getElementById("someButton")
simulatorRunButton!!.addEventListener("click", {
    launch(EmptyCoroutineContext) {
        doSomething()
    }
})
```

Of course, after doing that I had to erase the `onclick` part from my HTML object, something like this:

```
<button id="someButton" class="button">Click Me</button>
```